# Javascript: Flot: Pie Chart doesn't show up in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, flot

I'm using a javascript library called flot (http://code.google.com/p/flot/) to render graphs and charts and such.

This is my code http://jsfiddle.net/nQvEW/1/

I'm using the absolute latest version of everything (except for IE).

I've tested the fiddle in Safari, FF, Chrome, winFF, winChrome and IE.

As far as I can tell, there isn't a way to debug javascript in iE (no cosnole to show erros). So... I have no what the issue is.

Comment: what does F12 do? I'm not gonna push keyboard commands without knowing what they do.

Comment: lol sorry XD my bad.  F12 opens IEs developers tools. You can then go to the script tab for debugging.

Comment: ah, yeah. I tried using that... couldn't find a console though o.O

Comment: script tab.  It'll be on the right next to "Breakpoints", "Locals", "Watch", and "Call Stack"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you downloaded and included [explorer canvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/)? IE doesn't have a native canvas element which is used by flot to create the pie chart on. Download and include `excanvas.js` **before** you include the flot plugins.